# Facebook API : feed a carousel post (multi-photos)

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, carousel

For some time now, Facebook offers a new carousel post (basic feeding with link and many pictures) similar to the carousel ads, but every picture's link lead to the same page, it's a basic publication with text, link, image...
An sample of what I need (it's french, but sample images speak for itself:
http://www.leptidigital.fr/reseaux-sociaux/comment-creer-publication-facebook-carrousel-5612/

and the result about this news : 
https://www.facebook.com/leptidigital/posts/868750466554694

I've only find documentation about the carousel ads (payable) via marketing API.
Any body know if is possible with the standard API ? My research come to nothing...
Special thanks for every one !

Comment: If you look at that post in Graph API Explorer, you see that the images are in the `child_attachment` structure. And apparently, you can use that field when creating page posts, too: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/page/feed#publish

Comment: Thanks, that the good answer !!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) for the comment left explaining where to find this information.

> If you look at that post in Graph API Explorer, you see that the images are in the child_attachment structure. And apparently, you can use that field when creating page posts, too

[Facebook feed documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/page/feed#publish)

Here's an example in Python on how to accomplish what the documentation means:

```
import requests

post_data = {"access_token": "your access token",
             "message": "whatever you want to say"
             "link": "https://some.link"
             "child_attachments": '''[
                 {
                     "link": "http://some.link",
                     "picture": "https://app.replypro.io/media/wb3.jpg"
                 },
                 {
                     "link": "http://some.link",
                     "picture": "https://app.replypro.io/media/wb3.jpg"
                 }]'''}}
requests.post("https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/<your page id>/feed", data=post_data)
```

Comment: Wow, it works! Here is a way to test it live w the Explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/766891450409970/?method=POST&path=%7Bpage_id%7D%2Ffeed&version=v8.0&message=hello%20world&link=https%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com&child_attachments=[%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22link%22%3A%20%22https%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2Fitem1%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22picture%22%3A%20%22https%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2Fimage1.png%22%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22link%22%3A%20%22https%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2Fitem2%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22picture%22%3A%20%22https%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2Fimage2.png%22%0A%20%20%7D%0A]