# Facebook API : feed a carousel post (video and photos)

Tags: php, facebook, curl, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to create a carousel (non-ad) post using facebook's API that contains both video and image but I'm not able to post the video.

I have read: [Facebook API : feed a carousel post (multi-photos)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35845042/facebook-api-feed-a-carousel-post-multi-photos). I have successfully posted the image. However I can't post videos to it. Is there a way to post the whole video? I see a few sites they can do. Is there any solution or hack. Thank you.